# how can i get my code to work, i keep getting name not defined once i run it

Tags: python

```
T = int(input("food i have?: "))
for x in range(0, T):
     value = float(input("What is the value of item %d: "))

myAns.append(value)
myAns.sort()
print("The result is: ", myAns)
```

then i get the following NameError: name 'myAns' is not defined

Comment: ...where exactly do you think `myAns` gets created? When you run `myAns.append(value)`, what are you running `.append()` _on_?

Comment: (Also, you probably want to do the appending inside the loop?)

Comment: ok....i see where i messed up, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should add to the top:

```
myAns = []
```

or:

```
myAns = list()
```

I think your code should be:

```
T = int(input("food i have?: "))
myAns = []
for x in range(0, T):
    value = float(input("What is the value of item {}: ".format(x+1)))
    myAns.append(value)
myAns.sort()
print("The result is:", myAns)
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to define myAns above

```
T = int(input("food i have?: "))
myAns = []
for x in range(0, T):
    value = float(input("What is the value of item %d: "))
    myAns.append(value)
myAns.sort()
print("The result is: ", myAns)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append to myAns after reach loop, so it must be indented.

```
myAns.append(value)
```

It also must be defined in advance.

```
myAns=[]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you need to initialize your `myAns` list before appending to it.

```
T = int(input("food i have?: "))
myAns = []
for x in range(0, T):
    value = float(input("What is the value of item %d: " % x))
    myAns.append(value)
myAns.sort()
print("The result is: ", myAns)
```

Live Code -> https://onlinegdb.com/SyDoV9VoU